# Java replaceAll with regex

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have this input from the user:

```
*.*.*.*
```

(* = censor)
this string is an input from the user, that's what the user wants to censor. how do I convert it to regex?
Edit: Let me explain again. user wants to censor anything in * between the dots, so he types in `*.*.*.*`, and I need to convert it to regex. he could type text*text too

I have tried doing:

```
String strLine = "93.38.31.43 and 39.53.19.33 and lala.lala.lala.lala";
String input = "*.*.*.*";
String replaceWord = "[censor]";
input = input.replaceAll("\\*","\\\\\\w+");
strLine = strLine.replaceAll("(?=\\s+)\\S*)" + input + "(?=\\s+)\\S*",replaceWord);
```

I tried replacing the * with \\w+ to get this output:

> the ip's are [censor] and [censor] and [censor]

but It does not work, doesn't replace anything.

when I'm doing it like that, it works:

```
strLine = strLine.replaceAll("?<=\\s+)\\S*" +"\\w+\\.\\w+\\.\\w+\\.\\w+"+"(?\\s+)\\S*",replaceWord);
```

why doesn't it work? is there a better way doing it?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Here's a [great tool for testing Java-style regexes](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) (and it provides the Java-escaped string too!)

Comment: did you copied your code and pasted it here? because you have a wrong spelling in `replaceWord` you typed an `w` instead of an `e`

Comment: what does `*` mean? Is it anything? Is it a digit? Is it anything but space? There are filename globs, but this input is not a file name. You should educate user about proper regular expressions or provide him some kind of constructor for that expressions. `*.*.*.*` looks like self-invented regular-expression-like language. You should stick to standards.

Comment: Let me explain. user wants to censor anything between the dots now, so he types in .*.*.*, and I need to convert it to regex. he could type text*text too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
String strLine = "93.38.31.43 and 39.53.19.33 and lala.lala.lala.lala";
String input = "*.*.*.*";
String replaceWord = "[censor]";

input = input.replace("*","\\w+").replace(".", "\\.");
System.out.println(input); // \w+\.\w+\.\w+\.\w+

strLine = strLine.replaceAll("\\b" + input + "\\b", replaceWord);
System.out.println(strLine);
//=> [censor] and [censor] and [censor]
```

Comment: input = input.replace("*","\\w+").replace(".", "\\."); gives me an error.

Comment: @Tom An error. Wow. The content of the error message is a secret?

Comment: I fixed it adding \\ before the special chars and using replaceAll

Comment: Yes I know, weird. I'm using Eclipse and it gives me an error unless I will add \\ before

Comment: `input.replaceAll("\\*","\\\\\\w+").replaceAll("\\.", "\\\\.");` uses regex replacement and `input = input.replace("*","\\w+").replace(".", "\\.");` just does String replacement. Both should work.